# How to merge array items according to a specific property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, mapping, reduce

I'm trying to find the simplest way to merge this dynamic array using jQuery.

This is the result I'm getting after trying to use **.reduce**. The Month/Year object is dynamic, the result is based on the date range.

```
[
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 1,
        "Jan 2022": "Project1",
        "Feb 2022": 0,
        "Mar 2022": 0,
        "Apr 2022": 0,
        "May 2022": 0
    },
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 1,
        "Jan 2022": 0,
        "Feb 2022": "Project2",
        "Mar 2022": 0,
        "Apr 2022": 0,
        "May 2022": 0
    },
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 1,
        "Jan 2022": 0,
        "Feb 2022": 0,
        "Mar 2022": "Project3",
        "Apr 2022": 0,
        "May 2022": 0
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this

```
[
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 1,
        "Jan 2022": "Project1",
        "Feb 2022": "Project2",
        "Mar 2022": "Project3"
    }
]
```

This is what I've tried in jQuery

```
var monthNames = data
        .map(function (t) {
            var monthName = formatMonthYear(t.dynamicHeaderColumn);
            return monthName;
        })
        .reduce(function (p, t) {
            if (p.indexOf(t) == -1)
                p.push(t);

            return p;
        }, []);

    // transform
    var result = data.reduce(function (p, t) {
        var monthName = formatMonthYear(t.dynamicHeaderColumn);

        var existing = p.filter(function (t2) {
            return t2.objectGroupingId == t.objectGroupingId;
        });

        if (existing.length) {
            existing[0][monthName] = t.projectName;
        } else {
            var n = {
                ObjectGroupingId: t.objectGroupingId
            };
            monthNames.forEach(function (m) {
                n[m] = 0;
            });

            n[monthName] = t.projectName;
            p.push(n);
        }

        return p;
    }, []);
    return result;
```

Is this possible? I'm not quite familiar in jQuery still learning it.

Comment: What you are trying to do would be easily solved by using a dictionary. The month and year would be the key. Before you insert into the dictionary check to see if the inserted value is non-zero. Once you do that you can send that dictionary to a list.

Comment: @JeffB Thank you. I'll check on this. I'm still learning programming currently using C# as backend. I'm trying to learn pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to achieve this task using a dictionary. I highly recommend you read up on how a dictionary works - they are very useful!

Just a quick explanation of the code, in `function(e,d)` the `i` is the index and `d` is the value. The second - `function(key, value)` is a little different. The `key` will return the value before the `:` instead of an index. This is because you are iterating over the values of an object (`{` and `}` define the start and end of the object). `value` will return anything to the right of the `:`.

Update: I have updated the code to allow for any number of ObjectGroups as well as a pure JavaScript version.

```js
var input = [
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 1,
        "Jan 2022": "Project1",
        "Feb 2022": 0,
        "Mar 2022": 0,
        "Apr 2022": 0,
        "May 2022": 0
    },
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 1,
        "Jan 2022": 0,
        "Feb 2022": "Project2",
        "Mar 2022": 0,
        "Apr 2022": 0,
        "May 2022": 0
    },
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 1,
        "Jan 2022": 0,
        "Feb 2022": 0,
        "Mar 2022": "Project3",
        "Apr 2022": 0,
        "May 2022": 0,
        "Jan 1900": 0
    },
    {
        "ObjectGroupingId": 2,
        "Jan 2022": 0,
        "Feb 2022": 0,
        "Mar 2022": 0,
        "Apr 2022": 0,
        "May 2022": 0,
        "Jan 1900": "Project10"
    }
]

var currentObjectGrouping = null;
var outputListJQuery = [];

$.each(input, function(i,d){
  $.each(d, function(key, value) {
    if(key === 'ObjectGroupingId') currentObjectGrouping = value;
    if(outputListJQuery[currentObjectGrouping] === undefined) outputListJQuery[currentObjectGrouping] = {};
    if(value !== 0) {
      outputListJQuery[currentObjectGrouping][key] = value;
    }
  });
});

outputListJQuery = outputListJQuery.filter(function( element ) {
   return element !== undefined;
})

console.log("This is using JQuery!");
console.log(outputListJQuery);

//Pure JavaScript

var outputListJavascript = [];

input.forEach(e => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(e)) {
    if(key === 'ObjectGroupingId') currentObjectGrouping = value;
    if(outputListJavascript[currentObjectGrouping] === undefined) outputListJavascript[currentObjectGrouping] = {};
    if(value !== 0) {
      outputListJavascript[currentObjectGrouping][key] = value;
    }
  }
});

outputListJavascript = outputListJavascript.filter(function( element ) {
   return element !== undefined;
})

console.log("This is using only JavaScript!");
console.log(outputListJavascript);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will be going to read about that.

Comment: @ImStillAStudent ... the OP should consider sticking to methods of built-in objects like `Array` and/or `Object` in order to traverse/transform a single pure data-structure especially since 1) the above implemented code does not exactly return the OP's desired result, 2) the code is not capable of handling items with different/varying `ObjectGroupingId` values, 3) jQuery is the wrong tool for such tasks anyhow.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Going from jQuery to javascript for this example would be trivial to be fair.  Dictionaries are javascript and it has a forEach() function. And if he wanted to add `ObjectGroupingId` in the resulting object he can just remove the first `if` in the second loop. To handle multiple types of `ObjectGroupingId` you just need to create a 2D map.

Comment: @JeffB ... what is referred  to as a *dictionary* is a simple object (a bag of key value pairs or entries). An object does not have a `forEach` method. Also what should it be good for. The OP is looking for an array of object items as the desired result. And as for ... _"To handle multiple types of `ObjectGroupingId` you just need to create a 2D map."_ ... the above code then could be as easily changed according to this requirement in order to demonstrate the difference of the implementation. The OP might not be ready yet, doing it all alone.

Comment: @PeterSeliger `Object.entries()` will let you iterate over an object. I updated the code to allow for any number of `ObjectGroups` and made the output exactly like the OPs example. Also added in a pure Javascript example.

Comment: @JeffB ... many thanks for the final changes.

Answer (score 2):

Why does the OP want to use jQuery? jQuery mainly targets the domain of querying and manipulating the DOM. The OP's task in contrast deals with a single pure data structure and how to traverse/transform it.

Thus the OP should stick to the OP's original approach which uses methods of built-in objects like `Array` and `Object`.

The next provided code example uses two nested [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) tasks in order to achieve exactly the OP's desired result ...

```js
function collectGroupedProjectData({ lookup, result }, { ObjectGroupingId, ...restData }) {
  let groupedData = lookup[ObjectGroupingId];

  if (!groupedData) {
    groupedData = lookup[ObjectGroupingId] = { ObjectGroupingId };

    result.push(groupedData);
  }
  Object
    .entries(restData)
    .reduce((group, [key, value]) => {

      if (value !== 0) {
        Object.assign(group, { [key]: value });
      }
      return group;

    }, groupedData);

  return { lookup, result };
}

const data = [{
  ObjectGroupingId: 1,
  'Jan 2022': 'Project1',
  'Feb 2022': 0,
  'Mar 2022': 0,
  'Apr 2022': 0,
  'May 2022': 0,
}, {
  ObjectGroupingId: 1,
  'Jan 2022': 0,
  'Feb 2022': 'Project2',
  'Mar 2022': 0,
  'Apr 2022': 0,
  'May 2022': 0,
}, {
  ObjectGroupingId: 1,
  'Jan 2022': 0,
  'Feb 2022': 0,
  'Mar 2022': 'Project3',
  'Apr 2022': 0,
  'May 2022': 0,
}, {
  ObjectGroupingId: 2,
  'Jan 2022': 'Project4',
  'Feb 2022': 0,
  'Mar 2022': 0,
  'Apr 2022': 0,
  'May 2022': 0,
}, {
  ObjectGroupingId: 2,
  'Jan 2022': 0,
  'Feb 2022': 'Project5',
  'Mar 2022': 0,
  'Apr 2022': 0,
  'May 2022': 0,
}, {
  ObjectGroupingId: 2,
  'Jan 2022': 0,
  'Feb 2022': 0,
  'Mar 2022': 'Project6',
  'Apr 2022': 0,
  'May 2022': 0,
}];

const listOfGroupedProjects = data
  .reduce(collectGroupedProjectData, { lookup: {}, result: [] }).result;

console.log({ listOfGroupedProjects });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a case where you have multiple `ObjectGroupingId`s the final result can be an object of objects where the high-level keys are the `ObjectGroupingId` values and the values the aggregated elements.

```js
const data = [{"ObjectGroupingId": 1,"Jan 2022": "Project1","Feb 2022": 0,"Mar 2022": 0,"Apr 2022": 0,"May 2022": 0},{"ObjectGroupingId": 1,"Jan 2022": 0,"Feb 2022": "Project2","Mar 2022": 0,"Apr 2022": 0,"May 2022": 0},{"ObjectGroupingId": 1,"Jan 2022": 0,"Feb 2022": 0,"Mar 2022": "Project3","Apr 2022": 0,"May 2022": 0},{"ObjectGroupingId": 2,"Jan 2022": "Project4","Feb 2022": 0,"Mar 2022": 0,"Apr 2022": 0,"May 2022": 0},{"ObjectGroupingId": 2,"Jan 2022": 0,"Feb 2022": "Project5","Mar 2022": 0,"Apr 2022": 0,"May 2022": 0},{"ObjectGroupingId": 2,"Jan 2022": 0,"Feb 2022": 0,"Mar 2022": "Project6","Apr 2022": 0,"May 2022": 0}];

const aggData = data.reduce((acc, {ObjectGroupingId:id,...rest}) =>
    ({...acc,[id]:{...acc[id], ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(rest).filter(([k,v]) => v !== 0))}}), {}
);

console.log( aggData );
```

Comment: Nice one liner - I like it, I think the only downside is that for a beginner programmer it is far too hard to read. But it is fancy!

Comment: @JeffB ... one-liners, especially the once with overlong lines and non speaking (non self describing) variable names are hard to read and maintain/refactor. They are acceptable for own pet projects (though one has to remember it after some month). But they are disliked within developer teams and feared by maintenance people.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Oh yea, I can get that. Even in linq for c# you need to make sure to break up the calls to make it more readable. It can be fun to see how condensed you can get code though.